# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning, in xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, linker-errors, mach-o, swift4.1, xcode9.4

I update xcode version 9.4 to 10.2.1, I have created a project on xcode 9.4, run it once on xcode 10.2.1 and then delete this version and switch back to xcode 9.4 due to some reasons ... when I tried to run project on xcode 9.4 it gives lot of warnings and 198 errors

[image]

how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you opened the project on XCode 10.2.1 did you allow the project to be updated to the "recommended settings"?

It would have appeared as the yellow yield icon in the issues log.

A possible solution is to go into Time Machine (hopefully you keep backups) and revert your project folder to a copy from before you updated XCode

Answer (score 2):

If it's only linker errors, try to clear derived data on Xcode (Which you can access from Xcode > Preferences > Locations) and run application after clean and build. Some times your lesser disk spay might caused to these kind of issues as well.